# How to read JSON Object Array with Xamarin Android Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello guys I have an app that I'm trying to get a Json Array response and put it into a TextView, but it has 5 Counts and I don't know how to use a for to read each field of the JsonArray here is the code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Android.Util;
using App4.Resources;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Org.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace App4
{
[Activity(Label = "App4", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    EditText edtcpf;
    Button btnConsumer;
    TextView txtcpf;
    RestRequest cpf { get; set; }
    public RestClient consumer { get; set; }
    IRestResponse mensagemConsumer;
    TextView txtsobrenome;
    RestClient orderId { get; set; }
    RestRequest requestorderId { get; set; }
    IRestResponse answerorder { get; set; }
    TextView txtnome;
    TextView txtorder;
    TextView txtmensagem;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        btnConsumer = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConsumer);
        edtcpf = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtcpf);
        txtcpf = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtcpf);
        txtsobrenome = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtresposta);
        txtnome = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNome);
        txtorder = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtorder);
        txtmensagem = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtMensagem);
        btnConsumer.Click += BtnConsumer_Click;

    }

    private void BtnConsumer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // API Consumer CPF

            consumer = new RestClient("https://qa.api-latam.whirlpool.com/v1.0/consumers");
            cpf = new RestRequest("/" + edtcpf.Text, Method.GET);
            cpf.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            cpf.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 70197e6c-d81b-384c-bb32-d69e8c10b101");
            mensagemConsumer = consumer.Execute(cpf);
            Pessoa pessoa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pessoa>(mensagemConsumer.Content);
            txtnome.Text = "Nome: " +pessoa.firstName;
            txtsobrenome.Text = "Sobrenome: "+ pessoa.lastName;

            // API Consumer Appliances
            orderId = new RestClient("https://qa.api-latam.whirlpool.com/v1.0/consumers/");
            requestorderId = new RestRequest("/"+ edtcpf.Text+ "/service-orders", Method.GET);
            requestorderId.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            requestorderId.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 70197e6c-d81b-384c-bb32-d69e8c10b101");
            answerorder = orderId.Execute(requestorderId);
            var requestToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(answerorder.Content);
            var parse = JObject.Parse(answerorder.Content);
            var QtdeItens = parse.Count;
            var end = "";
            /*foreach (Dictionary<string, Order2> kvp in Order)
            {
                txtorder.Text = "Id: " + kvp.Value.orderId;

            }*/


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }




    }


}
```

}

I created a class on http://json2csharp.com/ and here is the class that I'm using to get the values. **The JSON answer depoends on the Id number that the person set, so it can be diferent every time I did this test using the ID 181.299.668-32**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Order2
{
public object orderId { get; set; }
public string orderStatusCode { get; set; }
public string orderStatusDescription { get; set; }
public int serviceProviderId { get; set; }
public string orderOpeningDate { get; set; }
public string orderSchedulingDate { get; set; }
public string orderSchedulingPeriod { get; set; }
public object orderSettlementDate { get; set; }
public object orderCancellationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
public Order2 order { get; set; }
}

   public class RootObject
   {
   public List<Order> orders { get; set; }
   }
```

So the answer that the json returns is : 
*{"orders":[{"order":{"orderId":7004093603,"orderStatusCode":"CANC","orderStatusDescription":"Cancelado","serviceProviderId":3649,"orderOpeningDate":"2015-07-07","orderSchedulingDate":"2015-07-18","orderSchedulingPeriod":"M","orderSettlementDate":null,"orderCancellationDate":null}},{"order":{"orderId":7004153791,"orderStatusCode":"AGEN","orderStatusDescription":"Agendado","serviceProviderId":3524,"orderOpeningDate":"2016-08-31","orderSchedulingDate":"2016-09-01","orderSchedulingPeriod":"M","orderSettlementDate":null,"orderCancellationDate":null}},{"order":{"orderId":7004156972,"orderStatusCode":"ABRT","orderStatusDescription":"Aberto","serviceProviderId":30820,"orderOpeningDate":"2017-04-13","orderSchedulingDate":null,"orderSchedulingPeriod":null,"orderSettlementDate":null,"orderCancellationDate":null}},{"order":{"orderId":7002178478,"orderStatusCode":"CANC","orderStatusDescription":"Cancelado","serviceProviderId":3555,"orderOpeningDate":"2014-02-22","orderSchedulingDate":"2014-02-24","orderSchedulingPeriod":"M","orderSettlementDate":null,"orderCancellationDate":null}},{"order":{"orderId":7002118317,"orderStatusCode":"CANC","orderStatusDescription":"Cancelado","serviceProviderId":3555,"orderOpeningDate":"2014-02-10","orderSchedulingDate":"2014-02-15","orderSchedulingPeriod":"M","orderSettlementDate":null,"orderCancellationDate":null}}]}*

And JsonViewer said that it has 5 counts, so **how can I do a for or foreach to read the orderId, orderStatus code, orderStatusDescription and orderOpeningDate because dependiing on the Id it has from 0 to 10 counts**

[EDIT]

Using the method:

```
foreach (var order in requestToken.orders)
            {

                    object vader = order.order.orderId;
                    string darth = Convert.ToString(vader);
                    txtorder.Text = darth;
                    txtorder.Text = order.order.orderStatusDescription;
                    txtorder.Text = order.order.orderStatusCode.;
               }
```

It returned one orderId :) . My doubt is: it's calling the **orderId of the count 0 automatically** how can I call the others orderIds? Is it like this?

```
               foreach (var order in requestToken.orders)
            {
                //for (var i = 0; i < requestToken.orders.Count; i++)
                //{
                    object vader = order.order.orderId[1], [2], etc;
                    string darth = Convert.ToString(vader);
                    txtorder.Text = darth;
                    txtorder.Text = order.order.orderStatusDescription;
                    txtorder.Text = order.order.orderStatusCode.;
                //}
```

Thank you guys for helping me

Comment: requestToken should contain all information you needed. Just use
foreach (var order in requestToken.orders) {
  // do what you want
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Deserialize JSON string

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Then run foreach loop

```
foreach(var orders in data)
{
    var Id = orders.order.orderId;
    ///and so on...
}
```

Comment: Using the method:

foreach (var order in requestToken.orders)
            {

                    object vader = order.order.orderId;
                    string darth = Convert.ToString(vader);
                    txtorder.Text = darth;
                    txtorder.Text = order.order.orderStatusDescription;
                    txtorder.Text = order.order.orderStatusCode.;
               }
It returned one orderId :) . My doubt is: it's calling the orderId of the count 0 automatically how can I call the others orderIds?

   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values like this:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
var orderIds = new List<long>();
foreach (var order in test.orders)
{
    var vader = order.order.orderId;
    orderIds.Add(vader);
}
```

Note that the orderIds are overwritten to the `vader` variable in each iteration of the loop. If you want to keep them, you need a collection (a list named `orderIds` in my example) and in each iteration you add to that collection. Finally all the `orderId`s will be in `orderIds`.

Comment: Using the method:

foreach (var order in requestToken.orders)
            {

                    object vader = order.order.orderId;
                    string darth = Convert.ToString(vader);
                    txtorder.Text = darth;
                    txtorder.Text = order.order.orderStatusDescription;
                    txtorder.Text = order.order.orderStatusCode.;
               }
It returned one orderId :) . My doubt is: it's calling the orderId of the count 0 automatically how can I call the others orderIds?

   Thank you

Comment: Do you want to extract all the orderIds and keep them somewhere, in a list for example?

Comment: Yes I want to extract them and show them in the app